# tapply() function dependent on multiple columns in R

Tags: r, summarization

In **R**, I have a table with Location, sample_year and count. So,

```
Location sample_year count  
A        1995        1
A        1995        1  
A        2000        3  
B        2000        1  
B        2000        1  
B        2000        5
```

I want a summary table that examines both the 'Location' and 'sample_year' columns and sums 'count' dependent on this unique combination instead of just a single column. So, end result should be:

```
Location sample_year sum_count
A        1995        2
A        2000        3
B        2000        7
```

I could merge columns and data into a new column to create unique a Location-sample_year but this is not a clean solution, esp if I need to scale it up to three columns at some point.  There must be a better approach.

Comment: This is not really a tapply() question, perhaps edit the title to be more general? You can get the sum with tapply, but still need to clean up the aggregated columns:  tapply(x$count, paste(x$Location, x$sample_year), sum)

Answer (score 11):

You can use `aggregate` with a formula.

First the data:

```
x <- read.table(textConnection("Location sample_year count  
A        1995        1
A        1995        1  
A        2000        3  
B        2000        1  
B        2000        1  
B        2000        5"), header = TRUE)
```

Aggregate using sum with a formula specifying the grouping:

```
aggregate(count ~ Location+sample_year, data = x, sum)
    Location sample_year count
1        A        1995     2
2        A        2000     3
3        B        2000     7
```

Comment: +1 Neat one-liner... It's always better to use functions available in base R distribution.

Comment: I would not say "always", there are easier to use tools like reshape (and plyr, and stringr, raster, ...) that can allow you to do more in smarter ways, I just haven't made the effort to learn and I get by with the older stuff because I just learnt that way. If I knew the new stuff I would suggest it as well, I voted on your answer!

Comment: IMHO, `reshape` pays off only in case of complex aggregation. `plyr` is another cool package that's really worth learning.

Answer (score 4):

Or with `reshape` package:

```
library(reshape)
md <- melt(x, measure.vars = "count")
cast(md, Location + sample_year ~ variable, sum)
  Location sample_year count
1        A        1995     2
2        A        2000     3
3        B        2000     7
```

***EDIT:***

I used object `x` from @mdsumner's answer. Anyway... I recommend you to stick with his answer, since it doesn't depend on external packages (`aggregate` function comes bundled with R, unless you detach `stats` package...). And, BTW, it's faster than `reshape` solution.

Answer (score 2):

Or with `plyr` (using `x` from @mdsummer)

```
library(plyr)
ddply(x, .(Location,sample_year), summarise, count = sum(count))
```